# How can i display and bring column value out of foreach loop and out of table in MVC view?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have the follwing code in MVC view :

```
<div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">
            <h5 class="text-uppercase p-2 text-center">Parasitology Department</h5>  
            <table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabParaResult.FirstOrDefault().patient_no)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabParaResult.FirstOrDefault().SERIAL)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabParaResult.FirstOrDefault().TEXT)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabParaResult.FirstOrDefault().VALUE)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabParaResult.FirstOrDefault().unit)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabParaResult.FirstOrDefault().reference_range)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabParaResult.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.patients.FirstOrDefault().Patient_Name)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.labtests.FirstOrDefault().TestName)</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var employee in Model.LabParaResult.Where(x => para.Contains(x.LabTests.Dept_id.GetValueOrDefault())))
            {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@employee.patient_no</td>
                        <td>@employee.SERIAL</td>
                        <td>@employee.TEXT</td>
                        <td>@employee.VALUE</td>
                        <td>@employee.unit</td>
                        <td>@employee.reference_range</td>
                        <td>@employee.APPROVED_DATE</td>
                        <td>@employee.Patients.Patient_Name</td>
                        <td>@employee.LabTests.TestName</td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
```

I need to bring and read the test name and patient name out of the `foreach` loop and out of table and show it next of Parasitology Department in the same row:

```
<h5 class="text-uppercase p-2 text-center">Parasitology Department</h5>
<td>@employee.Patients.Patient_Name</td>
 <td>@employee.LabTests.TestName</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code , if you dont have that columns in the table LabParaResult you can create SQL SERVER VIEW to read data you need from multiple tables and call it here  :

```
<dl>
 <dd >@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LabParaResult.First().Test_Name)</dd>
 <dd >@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LabParaResult.First().Patient_Name)</dd>
 </dl>
```